# Table header overlap Column bar

Tags: excel, header

Dummy here. I always use Freeze Pane to freeze the first row of the Table, but recently I downloaded an exercise file where the first row of it is frozen without using Freeze Pane function.

Please tell me what's it called and how can I set this to my table?

Thank you

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w1yH.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is known as an Excel table. You can create it in two ways - by selecting the range and then go to `Home` -> `Format as table` or `Insert` -> `Table`. There can be several tables on one sheet.

You can read more in [Overview of Excel tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)